# Does dereferencing pointer cast violate strict aliasing?

Tags: c, pointers, macros, dereference

Does this violate strict aliasing (or any other spec rules)?

```
void *get_int_ptr(void)
{
    static int ival = 0;
    return (void*)&ival;
}

#define GET_INT() *((int*)get_int_ptr())

void main()
{
    GET_INT() = 123;
    printf("%i", GET_INT());
}
```

This is a simplification, the actual code works with members of a discriminated union.

Comment: Not if the pointer is `void *`

Comment: *This is a simplification, the actual code...*  Post the actual code.  Specifics **matter**.

Comment: The only problems I see with that code is that it's not portable (because of `void main()` instead of `int main(void)`) and that it's missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: The object in the example is of  of type `int` and is only accessed via `int` pointer. So there is no aliasing here at all.

Comment: show us not simplified code only the actual.

Comment: I would suggest to avoid pointer punning

Answer (score 3):

> Does this violate strict aliasing (or any other spec rules)?

No it does not. From the [C23 draft](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3054.pdf):

[6.3.2.3 Pointers]

1. A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: Even if it wasn't `void` pointer, it wouldn't be aliasing. There might be other issues, but not related to strict aliasing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. One could `(long long*)(void*)` cast it and get a type with a different alignment requirement, but as long as it cast back to an `int*` before dereferenced, the paragraph above will hold.

Comment: @TedLyngmo *One could `(long long*)(void*)` cast it and get a type with a different alignment requirement, but as long as it cast back to an `int*` before dereferenced, the paragraph above will hold*  [No, that's not true](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. **If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined**."  Merely creating an address/pointer of a certain type invokes any alignment requirements and resulting UB if they're not met.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The alignment issue is not an aliasing issue. Eugene Sh. wrote that using a different pointer type for the intermediate type is not an aliasing issue, and that is correct. The alignment issue is an alignment issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle and Eric Oh, yes, that's true. My mistake mixing them up. Still, the code in question does not violate strict aliasing or any other spec rules. Hope the answer is correct as-is.